# Why isn't the rails server working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The Following is the response that the terminal gives me once I run the rails server command. I am on Linux Ubuntu

```
/home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:48:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /home/tor/Desktop/hello/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/tor/Desktop/hello/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /home/tor/Desktop/hello/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/spring-1.3.6/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/tor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/tor/Desktop/hello/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: As it says, can't find a js runtime.  So install one.  The rubyracer is included in the Gemfile by rails, uncomment that and bundle again.

Answer (score 1):

Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.

The answer is in your error message, you need to install a JS runtime from the page listed.

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment **therubyrace**r in your Gemfile

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

then you will have to do

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these gems:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'execjs'
```

Then run `bundle install`.